# TextBox TextChanged event fired issue when MainWindow load event exist

Tags: c#, wpf, vb.net, winforms

Following picture shows what my project is.

[image: My project]

Here is the my project codes for your testing needs.

```
<Window x:Class="MainWindow"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
Title="MainWindow" Height="150" Width="400">
<Grid>
    <TextBox Name="TextBox1" Width="200" Height="30" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Background="Pink" />
    <Button Name="Button1" Content="Button1" Width="125" Height="30" HorizontalAlignment="Right" IsEnabled="False" />
</Grid>
</Window>
```

...

```
Class MainWindow 

Private Sub MainWindow_Loaded(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs) Handles Me.Loaded
    TextBox1.Text = "Hello"
End Sub

Private Sub TextBox1_TextChanged(sender As System.Object, e As System.Windows.Controls.TextChangedEventArgs) Handles TextBox1.TextChanged
    Button1.IsEnabled = True
End Sub

End Class
```

When I run the codes above TextBox1_TextChanged event fired because of MainWindow_Loaded event.

Do you have any idea how to fire TextBox1_TextChanged event after MainWindow_Loaded?

Answer (score 0):

when textbo1 is generating its text property changes and and the event is being triggered. You can add event handler to textbox1 after form loaded like this

```
Public Class Form1
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    AddHandler TextBox1.TextChanged, AddressOf TextBox1_TextChanged
End Sub
Private Sub TextBox1_TextChanged()
    Button1.Enabled = True
End Sub End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

If the button should only be enabled when the textbox has some text in it, you need to check that in the event handler. If you need any additional validation, you'd do that here, too.

```
Private Sub TextBox1_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As TextChangedEventArgs) Handles TextBox1.TextChanged
    Button1.IsEnabled = (TextBox1.Text.Length > 0)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved.

```
Private Sub TextBox1_TextChanged(sender As System.Object, e As System.Windows.Controls.TextChangedEventArgs) Handles TextBox1.TextChanged
    If TextBox1.IsFocused Then
        Button1.IsEnabled = True
    End If
End Sub
```